# Update the UUID's in bulk insert query in google sheet

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-sheets

I've Bulk insert query and I want to insert it into an existing database. We want to update the existing uuid's so that we don't get duplicate reference error while running this bulk insert query.

I copied all the insert queries to a google sheet in column B and generated a new set of UUID's in another column A.
Here I'm not seeing any function or solution to replace the UUID's present in column B insert queries with newly generated Column A UUID's. The Id's highlighted in the below screenshot needs to be updated.

[Insert Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZurG.png)

Comment: Please add your examples as text, not pictures. It also helps if you add a `create table` statement for the table these inserts are supposed to populate - that way it's easier to reproduce your case.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL 13+ there's a built-in [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html). In older versions there's `uuid-ossp` extension that offers [`uuid_generate_v4()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/uuid-ossp.html#UUID-OSSP-FUNCTIONS). You can use those directly in your `insert` statements instead of the id you wish to replace:

```sql
INSERT INTO timeline_event 
VALUES (
    gen_random_uuid(),
    '2022-09-07 10:08:55.048',
    NULL,
    0,
    '2022-09-07 10:08:55.048',
    0,
    1,
    false,
    NULL,
    'CONFIGURATION',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'f691d7c9-18a3-4c32-bd25-876f6e4ec19f'::uuid,
    'd1ac2ff7-01a6-4f5f-b1fe-d823253d2fa8'::uuid,
    '03000337-1918-4277-aeef-cc9b3bca543f'::uuid,
    '4c6a3248-f14b-4653-9627-47c15cec503d'::uuid )
returning *;
```

You can even add them at the end of your statements in an [`on conflict` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to fire whenever there's a collision (as long as the `id` column has `unique` constraint): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/t3zIL7kQ)

```sql
INSERT INTO timeline_event 
VALUES (
    '2e1c5231-ba19-4c27-bedc-bef6c4066d75'::uuid,
    '2022-09-07 10:08:55.048',
    NULL,
    0,
    '2022-09-07 10:08:55.048',
    0,
    1,
    false,
    NULL,
    'CONFIGURATION',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'f691d7c9-18a3-4c32-bd25-876f6e4ec19f'::uuid,
    'd1ac2ff7-01a6-4f5f-b1fe-d823253d2fa8'::uuid,
    '03000337-1918-4277-aeef-cc9b3bca543f'::uuid,
    '4c6a3248-f14b-4653-9627-47c15cec503d'::uuid )
on conflict (id) do update set id=gen_random_uuid() --this
returning *;
```